# How to create image border?

Tags: vba, macos, image, ms-word, border

In Word for Mac, I'm trying to do something like this:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?48376-VBA-Macro-To-Insert-Border-For-All-Images

Given an inline image with no border, I select it, then in the immediate window do:

```
Selection.InlineShapes(1).Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle ' value 1
```

Word for Mac accepts this, but if I then inspect

```
Selection.InlineShapes(1).Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle
```

I see the value is still zero. There's no border line on the image either. Which means when I try setting any of the other left border properties it fails, with error 5843.

If I set up a border using the shape-properties dialog, the LineStyle is correctly shown as 1.

I don't think there's this problem in Word for Windows.

Comment: Even Selection.InlineShapes(1).Borders.Enable = True doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with Applescript and heaven knows what else, I finally discovered that the Microsoft documentation and the VBAExpress recipe are simply wrong (at least for Word 2016).

Instead of the Borders object, use the Line object:

```
With Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    .Line.Visible = lineVisible
    If lineVisible <> False Then
        .Line.Style = lineStyle
        .Line.Weight = lineWeight
        .Line.ForeColor = lineColor
    End If
End With
```

See https://github.com/charlesweir/WordImagesAndTables/blob/master/FiguresAndTables.bas for the related code and context.